# memory leak in *ProC file

Tags: database, memory-leaks, proc

I have some memory leak in my file and valgrind points to the code given below in the .cc file

```
sqlcxt(&ctx, &sqlctx, &sqlstm, &sqlfpn);
```

The code doesnot have this directly.The code is

```
            SQLDA *bind_dp;
            SQLDA *select_dp;

            /* Allocate memory for the select and bind descriptors. */
            if (!Db::alloc_descriptors(MAX_ITEMS, MAX_VNAME_LEN, MAX_INAME_LEN, bind_dp, select_dp))
                    goto errexit;
     EXEC SQL WHENEVER SQLERROR GOTO errexit_select;
            EXEC SQL PREPARE S FROM :query;
            EXEC SQL DECLARE C CURSOR FOR S;

            Db::set_bind_variables(bind_dp, &paramList);

            EXEC SQL OPEN C USING DESCRIPTOR bind_dp;

            Db::process_select_list(select_dp, dbQueryRsp);

            /* When done, free the memory allocated for
   pointers in the bind and select descriptors. */
            for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ITEMS; i++)
            {
                    if (bind_dp->V[i] != (char *) 0)
                            free(bind_dp->V[i]);
                    free(bind_dp->I[i]);   /* MAX_ITEMS were allocated. */
                    if (select_dp->V[i] != (char *) 0)
                            free(select_dp->V[i]);
                    free(select_dp->I[i]); /* MAX_ITEMS were allocated. */
            }

            /* Free space used by the descriptors themselves. */
            SQLSQLDAFree( ctx, bind_dp);
            SQLSQLDAFree( ctx, select_dp);

            EXEC SQL WHENEVER SQLERROR CONTINUE;
            /* Close the cursor. */
            EXEC SQL CLOSE C;
```

The alloc_descriptors is as follows:

```
bool Db::alloc_descriptors(int size, int max_vname_len, int max_iname_len, SQLDA *&bind_dp, SQLDA *&select_dp)

{
    GET_CONTEXT_DEFINE_SQLCA;
    EXEC SQL CONTEXT USE :ctx;
 if ((bind_dp =
   SQLSQLDAAlloc(ctx, size, max_vname_len, max_iname_len)) ==
     (SQLDA *) 0)
 {
            logMsg(DEBUG, 2,"Cannot allocate memory for bind descriptor.");
            return false;  /* Have to exit in this case. */
 }

 if ((select_dp =
     SQLSQLDAAlloc (ctx, size, max_vname_len, max_iname_len)) ==
        (SQLDA *) 0)
 {
     logMsg(DEBUG, 2,"Cannot allocate memory for select descriptor.");
     return false;
 }
 select_dp->N = MAX_ITEMS;

/* Allocate the pointers to the indicator variables, and the
   actual data. */
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ITEMS; i++) {
    bind_dp->I[i] = (short *) malloc(sizeof (short));
    select_dp->I[i] = (short *) malloc(sizeof(short));
    bind_dp->V[i] = (char *) malloc(1);
    select_dp->V[i] = (char *) malloc(1);
}

return true;
}
```

The total code i can give in the .cc file is

```
    /* EXEC SQL OPEN C USING DESCRIPTOR bind_dp; */

{
struct sqlexd sqlstm;
sqlstm.sqlvsn = 12;
sqlstm.arrsiz = 1;
sqlstm.sqladtp = &sqladt;
sqlstm.sqltdsp = &sqltds;
sqlstm.stmt = "";
sqlstm.iters = (unsigned int  )1;
sqlstm.offset = (unsigned int  )24;
sqlstm.selerr = (unsigned short)100;
sqlstm.cud = sqlcud0;
sqlstm.sqlest = (unsigned char  *)&sqlca;
sqlstm.sqlety = (unsigned short)4352;
sqlstm.occurs = (unsigned int  )0;
sqlstm.sqcmod = (unsigned int )0;
sqlstm.sqhstv[0] = (unsigned char  *)bind_dp;
sqlstm.sqhstl[0] = (unsigned long )0;
sqlstm.sqhsts[0] = (         int  )0;
sqlstm.sqindv[0] = (         short *)0;
sqlstm.sqinds[0] = (         int  )0;
sqlstm.sqharm[0] = (unsigned long )0;
sqlstm.sqadto[0] = (unsigned short )0;
sqlstm.sqtdso[0] = (unsigned short )0;
sqlstm.sqphsv = sqlstm.sqhstv;
sqlstm.sqphsl = sqlstm.sqhstl;
sqlstm.sqphss = sqlstm.sqhsts;
sqlstm.sqpind = sqlstm.sqindv;
sqlstm.sqpins = sqlstm.sqinds;
sqlstm.sqparm = sqlstm.sqharm;
sqlstm.sqparc = sqlstm.sqharc;
sqlstm.sqpadto = sqlstm.sqadto;  
sqlstm.sqptdso = sqlstm.sqtdso;
sqlcxt(&ctx, &sqlctx, &sqlstm, &sqlfpn);
}


 DbT::process_select_list(select_dp, dbQueryRsp);
```

can some one explain what does this mean.

The dump of valgrind is this:

```
==1212== 124 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 2,103 of 3,407
==1212==    at 0x4A078B8: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)
==1212==    by 0x643CC59: sqlalc (in /home/product/11.2.0/client_1/lib/libclntsh.so.11.1)
==1212==    by 0x7D32749: sqlbrl (in /home/product/11.2.0/client_1/lib/libclntsh.so.11.1)
==1212==    by 0x6D96B7A: sqlbds (in /home/product/11.2.0/client_1/lib/libclntsh.so.11.1)
==1212==    by 0x7D34543: sqlnst (in /home/product/11.2.0/client_1/lib/libclntsh.so.11.1)
==1212==    by 0x7D3068A: sqlcxt (in /home/product/11.2.0/client_1/lib/libclntsh.so.11.1)
==1212==    by 0x9440C25: execute(std::string const&, cil_cch_namespace::ParamTypeListList const&, cil_cch_namespace::QueryType&, long&, long&, ExtError&) (Db.cc:608)
==1212==    by 0x94430B0: execute(std::string const&, std::string&, long&, ExtError&) (Db.cc:474)
```

Comment: It looks like a callstack. You can look at the function which causes memory leak (which are in your source control).

Comment: if ((bind_dp =
       SQLSQLDAAlloc(ctx, size, max_vname_len, max_iname_len)) ==
         (SQLDA *) 0)
Iam using this to alloc the ctx and
 SQLSQLDAFree( ctx, bind_dp); frreing the ctx in the src, still it gives a memory leak

Comment: But the callstack tells different story. See the implementation the functions in the callstack.